# DX Package Install: No QuickAction named NewTask found

Tags: salesforcedx, error, package, scratch-org, quickaction

I am trying to install a package to a scratch org like so:

`$ sfdx force:package:install --wait 10 --publishwait 10 --package XXXXX@0.1.0-2 --installationkey XXXX --noprompt -u XXXX`

However, the installation fails with this error:
`ERROR:  Encountered errors installing the package!,Installation errors:
1) (Contact-EP Layout) In field: QuickAction - no QuickAction named NewTask found, Details: Contact-EP Layout: In field: QuickAction - no QuickAction named NewTask found`

On searching around, I found people who had errors with *NewEvent* or *NewEmail* and the solution was to turn on the email feature or events feature etc.

In my case I believe tasks is a feature that's always available and cannot be "disabled" as such and is enabled by default.

This is further confirmed by editing the default contact layout and pulling it to see an action called *NewTask* under `<quickActionList>`.

What do I need to do to solve this error?
As a temporary solution I commented out the entire *quickActionList*, but I would like to solve this properly.

Additional info:

I used this command to create the scratch org:

`$ sfdx force:org:create --definitionfile config/project-scratch-def.json --durationdays 1 --setalias XXXX --nonamespace`

The only difference between this and all the other scratch orgs I've tested on is the `--nonamespace` flag.

Comment: Does your target org have a Global Action called NewTask, a Contact-specific action with that name, or both?

Comment: @DavidReed a global action, I believe it's one of the default built-in ones

Comment: Interesting. I assume that you can deploy the unpackaged source of your app to the same scratch org without trouble? Are you building the package in a namespaced scratch org?

Comment: Typically, I see this when I deploy code to an org that does not have Chatter enabled (I have some old packaging orgs that pre-date Chatter) - so I would look at the Chatter settings as well

Answer (score 1):

Salesforce posted this article addressing this problem (which just kept me up for 3 hours): [Deployment error 'no QuickAction named NewTask found'](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000321931&type=1&mode=1)

It has some suggestions, but none of them worked for me. Eventually, I just ripped all Platform & Quick actions out of the package then added them back in post-deploy. May not work for ISV who can't access the org their packages go in, but at least its a work around if you can access your target org.